# Adding check boxes to allow multiple Delete & edit from my html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following table inside my asp.net mvc view:-

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr id="@item.TMSServerID">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit","Server", new { id=item.TMSServerID },null) |
            @if (!item.IsAlreadyAssigned()){ 

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
 "Delete", "Server",
new { id = item.TMSServerID },

new AjaxOptions
{ Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete (" + item.Technology.Tag.ToString() + ")",
    HttpMethod = "Post",

    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
})}
        </td>

        <td>
             @Html.ActionLink(item.Technology.Tag,"Details","Server",new { id = item.TMSServerID},null)
        </td>

        <td class="hidden-phone" >
            @item.status
        </td>
```

The table allow edit,delete single item at a time. But now I want to do the following:-

1. Add a checkbox beside each row.
2. Add a Ajax delete button to delete selected items
3. Add a Transfer ajax button, which allow editing the selected items  status.

So I am trying to achieve the following:-

1. How can I pass the item id + item timestamp field , using ajax button , as I need to check if the selected items has been modified by another user?
2. How I can remove the selected row from the html table incase the delete operation successed ?

Thanks

Comment: See [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) for a plug in on this.

Answer (score -1):

add a check box on each first cell of the table with ModelID as the value of each checkbox.

inside your foreach, include this:

```
<td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="TMSServerID" value="1"  />
</td>
```

add this into tha parameter of your controller: Int32[] idList, something like this:

```
  public void CheckForIds(Int32[] idList)
  {
     //Manipulate idList
  }
```

and in your button event, call the controller method.

You might want to take a look at this for your reference:

http://byatool.com/mvc/asp-net-mvc-how-to-handle-multiple-checkboxes-with-viewsactions-jquery-too/